# increasing value of passing address

Tags: c++

Hi All I have written a code

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
float *check(float *);

int main()
{

    float a = 7356, *b;
    b = &a;
    cout << b<<endl;
    cout << &a <<endl;
    b = check(&a);
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << &a << endl;
    cin.get();

}
float *check(float *r)
{
    r = r + 1;
    return r;
}
```

In the output i got

006FFB40

006FFB40

006FFB44

006FFB40

why is value of &a not increasing??

Comment: Because you can't change the address of a, it is at a fixed location on the stack.  You can change the value of b because it is a pointer that just happens to be set to &a at one point but can be set to any other address like &c or &d[125].  When b points to a it does not control the location of a, it is just able to read or write values to a.

Comment: I expect the value of `&a` (address of a) to be constant thoughout the scope of main. Also, C++ has pass-by-value semantics by default, *including the values of pointers.* changing a pointer inside a function generally doesn’t change pointers outside that function (although in this case you assign the returned value to `b`).

Comment: Note: I would recommend not doing this. It's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

`&a` means address of `a` in memory. Address of a variable can't change while it is in scope. Function parameters are local variables, unless they are references, so increasing pointer `r` in check just increases the value of local variable in `check`.

---

If you want to be able to change the original variable, you need to pass a reference:

```
float *check(float *&r)
{
    r = r + 1;
    return r;
}
```

But now call `check(&a)` will not compile, as now you need to pass an actual pointer variable. You can't have a modifiable reference to result of an expression like `&a`.

Also note that `check` function does not make much sense. Increasing pointer like that can produce UB and (especially if you turn on optimizations) programs which behave unpredictably and illogically.

Comment: so what type of input will we required in call for check func.

Comment: @rishipandey there is no way to do what you seem to want without violating the rules of the language and producing an unstable program. Perhaps you have misinterpreted what you need to do?

Comment: @rishipandey Depends on what you *actually* want to do.

Answer (score 2):

> why is value of &a not increasing??

Because you never modify `&a`. You assign `r` which is a parameter that is local to the function and you assign `b` which is a separate local variable, but you never assign `&a`. Just because those variables happens to have the same value as `&a`, doesn't mean that when their value changes, `&a` would change too. Would you expect the value of `i` to change in the following example?

```
int i = 42;
int j = i;
j += 1;
```

It doesn't change.

In fact, `&a` is something that you cannot modify. It is the address of the object named by that variable. The address of an object never changes through the lifetime of the object.